# How can Local_planner handle a Lidar blind spot

Tags: ros, navigation, lidar, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The lidar on my robot is on the front of the robot so the robot creates a blind spot behind the lidar. How can i get objects to not disappear on the local costmap when they go into the blind spot?

The lidar is reporting "inf" values in the blind spot.

I have `track_unknown_space: true` for the local_costmap

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226267/how-can-local_planner-handle-a-lidar-blind-spot./) by [trips323](https://answers.ros.org/users/24982/trips323/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can try to set the parameter `inf_is_valid: false` . in this way the local costmap (or global) will not treat scans with "inf" values.

this is a quick fix, and you may have problems with not clearing the costmaps in front of the robot if your sensor outputs "inf" for scans farther than `max_range`, for example. in that case you might want to use a filter to correct that kind of measurements from your data as in [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/30014/costmap-clearing-of-obstacles/?answer=30045#post-id-30045).

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1